Remove elements with same prefix from a string in a column
and thank you for being part of an awesome community of learners and explorers! :) I have an issue with removing elements from a character column. This answer pointed me in a correct direction (split string and keep only unique values in the dataframe), but I don't have duplicated values, just identical prefixes, and I want to eliminate them, not keep one of the values.
Here is an example:
tst <- data.frame(seqnames=as.factor(c(rep("chr1", 4))), 
           gene_id=c("ENSG00000237613", "ENSG00000243073", "ENSG00000081026", "ENSG00000287064"),
           sample_set=c("23-18t,27-21t", "18-16b,18-16t", "1-16t,19-16t", "1-16t,14-19b,14-19t,15-15b,17-15b,17-15t,19-16b,22-16b,22-16t,26-19b,26-19t,27-21b,27-21t,28-21b,28-21t,29-19b,29-19t,9-20b"))

The issue is column "sample_set". I have 2 types of samples, with suffix "b" or "t". I want to eliminate those that are a pair (e.g. "18-16b" and "18-16t" in row 2, "14-, 17-, 22-, 26-, 27" pairs in row 4, etc). If all samples are eliminated, the place can be left empty or the row can be deleted.
Basically, from this:

  seqnames         gene_id                                                                                                                  sample_set
1     chr1 ENSG00000237613                                                                                                               23-18t,27-21t
2     chr1 ENSG00000243073                                                                                                               18-16b,18-16t
3     chr1 ENSG00000081026                                                                                                                1-16t,19-16t
4     chr1 ENSG00000287064 1-16t,14-19b,14-19t,15-15b,17-15b,17-15t,19-16b,22-16b,22-16t,26-19b,26-19t,27-21b,27-21t,28-21b,28-21t,29-19b,29-19t,9-20b

To this:
  seqnames         gene_id                 sample_set
1     chr1 ENSG00000237613              23-18t,27-21t
2     chr1 ENSG00000243073                                 
3     chr1 ENSG00000081026               1-16t,19-16t
4     chr1 ENSG00000287064  1-16t,15-15b,19-16b,9-20b

So I worked myself onto a ledge. My approach was to create a logical vector that would help with the filtering.
I will exemplify only for row 4:
logical_vect <- unlist(map(str_extract_all(tst$sample_set[[4]], "([0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{2})"), unduplicated_values))
sample_values <- unlist(strsplit(tst$sample_set[[4]], ","))
sample_values[logical_vect]
# [1] "1-16t"  "15-15b" "19-16b" "9-20b" 

I didn't want to use the 'apply' family of functions to use this code on each row, I had the idea that it would be slow on a very large dataset, so I came up with this approach:
tst %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>%  

  ## extract only the number portion of the sample name
  ## for each row, get only the values that are not duplicated (if duplicated, delete both values) != unique()
  ## create a logical list out of it
  mutate(sample_logical = map(str_extract_all(sample_set, "([0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{2})"), unduplicated_values) ,
         ## create a list out of each sample set
         sample_set = strsplit(sample_set, ","))

## output:


# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   rowname [6]
  rowname seqnames gene_id         sample_set sample_logical
  <chr>   <fct>    <chr>           <list>     <list>        
1 1       chr1     ENSG00000237613 <chr [2]>  <lgl [2]>     
2 2       chr1     ENSG00000243073 <chr [2]>  <lgl [2]>     
3 3       chr1     ENSG00000081026 <chr [2]>  <lgl [2]>     
4 4       chr1     ENSG00000287064 <chr [18]> <lgl [18]>    

And here is where I am stuck, I have no idea how to use "sample_logical" to filter out each "sample_set" row. Any idea is welcomed and thank you for your time.

You could use a regular expression group capture and backreference to eliminate duplicates. This is faster (and more succinct) than iterating.
In the tidyverse:
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

tst |>
  mutate(sample_set = str_remove_all(sample_set, "(\\d+-\\d+)[tb],(\\1[tb],?)+"))

In base R (even faster if you set perl = TRUE):
tst$sample_set <- gsub("(\\d+-\\d+)[tb],(\\1[tb],?)+", "", tst$sample_set)

Using the stringfish package, if speed is really a concern. This has a pretty seamless transition from base R:
library(stringfish)

tst$sample_set <- sf_gsub("(\\d+-\\d+)[tb],(\\1[tb],?)+", "", tst$sample_set, nthreads = 4L)

You can then simply filter out these rows, if you want, with the condition nzchar(sample_set) using dplyr filter() or base R subset().
Benchmark
In case this is helpful, if you have a large data frame:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(stringfish)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  `LMc (tidyverse)` = {
    dat |>
      mutate(sample_set = str_remove_all(sample_set, "(\\d+-\\d+)[tb],(\\1[tb],?)+"))
  },
  `LMc (base R perl = T)` = {
    gsub("(\\d+-\\d+)[tb],(\\1[tb],?)+", "", dat$sample_set, perl = TRUE)
  },
  `LMc (base R)` = {
    gsub("(\\d+-\\d+)[tb],(\\1[tb],?)+", "", dat$sample_set)
  },
  `LMc (stringfish)` = {
    sf_gsub("(\\d+-\\d+)[tb],(\\1[tb],?)+", "", dat$sample_set, nthreads = 4L)
  },
  zx8754 = {
    sapply(strsplit(dat$sample_set, ","), \(i){
      x <- gsub("[tb]", "", i)
      paste(i[ !x %in% x[ duplicated(x) ] ], collapse = ",")
    })
  },
  `Andy Baxter` = {
    dat |>
      separate_longer_delim(sample_set, ",") |>
      unique() |>
      mutate(match_var = str_extract(sample_set, "([0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{2})")) |> 
      group_by(seqnames, gene_id) |> 
      add_count(match_var) |>
      filter(n < 2) |>
      summarise(sample_set = paste(sample_set, collapse = ","), .groups = "drop") |> 
      right_join(dat |> select(-sample_set), by = c("seqnames", "gene_id"))
  },
  times = 30L,
  setup = {
    dat <- tst[sample(seq_len(nrow(tst)), 1E5, replace = T),]
  }
)

Unit: microseconds
              expr       min        lq         mean    median        uq       max neval   cld
   LMc (tidyverse)  104746.6  107473.6  110720.9467  109890.1  112102.8  136915.9    30 a    
 LMc (base R perl)   66294.6   68620.7   70163.3167   70170.3   71000.1   75591.2    30 a    
      LMc (base R)  195559.5  198735.7  203297.3667  201604.9  206391.3  217460.7    30  b   
  LMc (stringfish)      96.4      98.8     128.8033     102.5     122.8     625.3    30   c  
            zx8754 2017099.1 2090961.7 2195822.9767 2170414.4 2296068.9 2428180.5    30    d 
       Andy Baxter  678323.4  758232.0  839141.4800  837078.8  933611.5 1064974.5    30     e


Thank you so very much for your help! It is so much easier and straightforward than what I was trying. I really need to learn how to use regular expression group capture.

Just one comment for the 3rd code you have recommended: maybe you meant stringfish instead of starfish. I found no R package for starfish.

Yes that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out! I've since corrected it. Group captures () + back references \\1 are a really common and efficient way of detecting duplication within a string, but it takes a bit to get used to them.

Also there was a typo in my regular expression that I fixed for the situation where you have more than one duplicate in a string (e.g. 18-16b,18-16t,18-16b), which you do not in your example, but just in case you do in your real data.

A tidier way of doing it in one flow would be to separate your column out into a longer format and reduce that way:
library(tidyverse)

tst <- tibble(seqnames=as.factor(c(rep("chr1", 4))), 
                  gene_id=c("ENSG00000237613", "ENSG00000243073", "ENSG00000081026", "ENSG00000287064"),
                  sample_set=c("23-18t,27-21t", "18-16b,18-16t", "1-16t,19-16t", "1-16t,14-19b,14-19t,15-15b,17-15b,17-15t,19-16b,22-16b,22-16t,26-19b,26-19t,27-21b,27-21t,28-21b,28-21t,29-19b,29-19t,9-20b"))


tst |>
  separate_longer_delim(sample_set, ",") |>
  unique() |>
  mutate(match_var = str_extract(sample_set, "([0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{2})")) |> 
  group_by(seqnames, gene_id) |> 
  add_count(match_var) |>
  filter(n < 2) |>
  summarise(sample_set = paste(sample_set, collapse = ",")) |> 
  right_join(tst |> select(-sample_set))
  # This final step ensures all rows are represented

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'seqnames'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> Joining with `by = join_by(seqnames, gene_id)`
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   seqnames [1]
#>   seqnames gene_id         sample_set               
#>   <fct>    <chr>           <chr>                    
#> 1 chr1     ENSG00000081026 1-16t,19-16t             
#> 2 chr1     ENSG00000237613 23-18t,27-21t            
#> 3 chr1     ENSG00000287064 1-16t,15-15b,19-16b,9-20b
#> 4 chr1     ENSG00000243073 <NA>


Thank you for the tidyverse option! I have actually used this piece of code for another analysis.

Remove t or b, check if they are duplicated:
sapply(strsplit(tst$sample_set, ","), \(i){
  x <- gsub("[tb]", "", i)
  paste(i[ !x %in% x[ duplicated(x) ] ], collapse = ",")
  })
# [1] "23-18t,27-21t"             ""                         
# [3] "1-16t,19-16t"              "1-16t,15-15b,19-16b,9-20b"

